# Intercept HTTP requests and responses on the host server

Tags: apache, http, iis, https

I have a need to be able to intercept `HTTP` and `HTTPS` requests and responses on the host servers (Windows and Linux). What is the best way of approaching this and are there any open-source libraries that I can make use of and extend to achieve this?

Sorry, I do not have a clue on how to achieve this and looking up online only throws up results for commercial products. I do not have the budget to use a commercial product to achieve this.

Comment: Can you give an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I would need to intercept the incoming requests and modify the response by adding a custom header depending on  the request.

Comment: May I know what technology are you using to develop your application? For traditional asp.net hosted in IIS, you could insert a custom HttpModule into IIS to intercept and add custom response header. For asp.net core, MiddleWare function as Httpmodule. So this issue depend on what technology and what platform are you using.

Comment: I need to implement the same solution on both .Net / Core applications on IIS and Java applications hosted on Apache.

Comment: Since apache, IIS are using totally different pipeline. I'm afraid it is hard to achieve this for all these platforms.  How about create a front-end proxy server? I think it should achieve your requirement.